# Poincaré-Bendixson criterion applied to non-autonomous dynamical systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, periodic-functions, chaos-theory

I'm fairly new to dynamical systems and chaos. I'm dealing with a second order non-autonomous system of differential equations:

$$\dot{x} = y    $$

$$\dot{y} = f(x,y,t)$$

I can further split $f$ as $$f(x,y,t) = g(x,t) + h(x,y,t)$$

I would like to find out if closed orbits and maybe a limit cycle exists for this system. Now, I understand that one way to check for closed orbits is to use the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem which is only applicable to 2-dimensional systems.

My question is, can this be applied to a two-dimensional non-autonomous system? Since a 2D non-autonomous system can be written as a 3D autonomous system with time as a state variable, would the PD theorem still be valid? If not, can you suggest another method that can be used to prove the existence or non-existence of closed orbits? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with "closed orbit"? A self-crossing solution or in the maximum a periodic solution? The latter might not exist.

Comment: Thank you. By closed orbit, I do mean a periodic solution. How do I prove that such a solution does not exist?  Would this still be the case if the time appeared explicitly as sines and cosines?

Comment: If you have periodic forcing, there might be periodic orbits. And they might even be stable. But you can as well get chaotic behavior. The Duffing oscillator $\ddot x +k \dot x - x+x^3=B\cos(t)$ is one simple example of that.

Comment: Thank you. That is true. However, how about periodic forcing associated with a damping term? ($\dot{x}\cos(t)$). I believe I can prove chaotic behaviour by showing that the system is non-integrable using Melnikov's method. However, does chaotic behaviour imply no periodic/quasi-periodic solutions?